# What's the effect of the parameters min_count & max_count in the boto.ec2.run_instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto

I'm reading boto's documentation: http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection.run_instances

```
Parameters: 
...    
min_count (int) – The minimum number of instances to launch.
max_count (int) – The maximum number of instances to launch.
...
```

I think that I should be able to create many instances at once using this two parameters but I don't understand their exact effect. I guess that `max_count` is the desired number of instances, and if everything works well I get `max_count` instances. I know that amazon might not let you create as many instances as you want so I suppose that `min_count` is used for something like "create at least `min_count` instances or do nothing". Is this right?

Also, when listing reservations using `boto.ec2.get_all_instances`, do I get a single reservation containing all the instances I created with the above command, or do I get a list of reservations each one containing an instance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of `min_count` and `max_count` is correct.  It is saying I really want you to create `max_count` instances but I'll take at least `min_count`.  If you can't create at least `min_count` then don't create any.

If the `run_instances` command works you will get back a single `Reservation` object which contains all of the created instances in the `instances` attribute.